# Change Background Image of View, NativeScript (Android application)

Tags: android, background-image, nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to change the background Image of a view of my android mobile application. I am using NativeScript to create a hybrid application but it is not working.

XML of the view

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" actionBarHidden="true" >
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <Image src="rec://logo" stretch="none" horizontalAlignment="center"/>
    <Button text="Click" />
    <Button text="Click"/>
</StackLayout>
```

CSS of the view:

```
Page{
background-image: url('~/images/back.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Note: the image that i want to put for the background is back.jpg and it is in the images folder under the app folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that background-image property needs a little tweak, I have it defined as follows and it works fine: `background-image: ~/images/bg_intro_pin.jpg`

Comment: when i remove "url("...")", it gives and error... and also i dint exactly get what you are trying to say. do i need to change the resolutions of the image?

Comment: Yeah sure, that's what VSCode might say, but at runtime it works just fine, right? At least if you actually have that image in /app/images.

Comment: It works fine now... 
Actually my emulator was on livesync and for some reason the change was not showing in livesync. However once i terminated livesync and ran the emulator the changes appeared. 

thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: Ah, good to hear! Don't forget to mark this as correct and enjoy your sunday!